# Update one column with values from another if the row is blank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with 2 columns Sector & Sector Name, I want to update 'Sector' = 'Sector Name' values  where 'Sector' is Blank

I have below script, but its giving error "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

```
dataFinal.loc[dataFinal['Sector'] == '', 'Sector'] = \
           dataFinal.loc[dataFinal['Sector Name'] != '', 'Sector Name']
```

Please help.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `dataFinal.loc[dataFinal['Sector'] == '', 'Sector'] = dataFinal['Sector Name']`?
`

Comment: @John Galt, thanks for response, after reset index its working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best is create unique index and then use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with inverted condition:

```
dataFinal = dataFinal.reset_index(drop=True)
#John Gals dol from comment 
dataFinal.loc[dataFinal['Sector'] == '', 'Sector'] = dataFinal['Sector Name']
```

Or:

```
m = dataFinal['Sector'] == ''
dataFinal['Sector'] = dataFinal['Sector'].mask(m, dataFinal['Sector Name'])
```

---

```
m = dataFinal['Sector'] != ''
dataFinal['Sector'] = dataFinal['Sector'].where(m, dataFinal['Sector Name'])
```

Sample:

```
dataFinal = pd.DataFrame({'Sector':['a','ss',''],
                         'Sector Name':['r','t','y']}, index=[4,4,1])
print (dataFinal)
  Sector Sector Name
4      a           r
4     ss           t
1                  y

dataFinal = dataFinal.reset_index(drop=True)

m = dataFinal['Sector'] == ''
dataFinal['Sector'] = dataFinal['Sector'].mask(m, dataFinal['Sector Name'])
print (dataFinal)
  Sector Sector Name
0      a           r
1     ss           t
2      y           y
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.where`

```
dataFinal['Sector'] = \
    np.where(dataFinal['Sector'] == '', dataFinal['Sector Name'], dataFinal['Sector'])
```

---

Thanks to [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46090487/4909087) for the data:

```
dataFinal

  Sector Sector Name
4      a           r
4     ss           t
1                  y

dataFinal['Sector'] = \
        np.where(dataFinal['Sector'] == '', dataFinal['Sector Name'], dataFinal['Sector'])
dataFinal
  Sector Sector Name
4      a           r
4     ss           t
1      y           y
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mask to find all rows in the dataframe where `Sector` only contains whitespace, and then use this mask to apply the corresponding `Sector Name`:

```
mask = dataFinal['Sector'].str.isspace()
dataFinal.loc[mask, 'Sector'] = dataFinal.loc[mask, 'Sector Name']
```